# How to put HTML5 favicon "this page is HTML5 powered"

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

So I want to put at the end of my address bar the html5 favicon and the text onmouseover "this page is HTML5 powered". How do I do that? I've searched everywhere...
Also, in Chrome, when I use this code

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.fattorefamiglia.com/wp-content/themes/child_care_creative/favicon.ico">
```

It only shows the favicon in the tab, not in the address bar. In firefox it works. Anyone knows? Thanks!

Comment: Chrome doesn't show any favicons in the address bar, only on the tabs. That is just the way Chrome handles favicons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such javascript events on favicons. They are managed by the browser and you have no control on it, so you cannot have a onmouseover event to display what you need. Furthermore, it is outside the viewport so it is the browser's job to deal with it.

In Chrome, the display of favicons in the address bar has been removed to prevent social engineering. Your favicon will only be displayed in the tab.